# Continous function iff $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$ or $x = 0$

Tags: limits, continuity

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given as $f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & \textrm{x = 0} \\
      0 & x \notin \mathbb{Q} \\
      \frac{1}{q} & x = \frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q} \\
   \end{cases} $ where $\frac{p}{q}$ is irreducible fraction. I have to prove that $f$ is continous in $x$ iff $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$ or $x = 0$. If $x = 0$ then $f(x)$ and for every $a_n \to 0$ we have $f(a_n) \to 0$ because we know that $\forall_{\epsilon > 0}{\exists_{N \in \mathbb{N}}{\forall_{n > N}{|a_n|<\epsilon}}}$ so we take $a_n$ for $n > N$ and if $a_n = 0$ or $a_n \notin\mathbb{Q}$ then $f(a_n) =0$ by definition, otherwise $|f(a_n)| < |a_n|$ so $|f(n)| < \epsilon$. How to make proof for other cases?

Comment: It's only a little bit similar to not the same.

Comment: @alex: It deals with the hardest part of your question. To show non-continuity at $x=\frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ and $q$ are integers, $q\gt 0$, and $p\ne 0$, note that $f(x)=1/q$ but every neighbourhood of $x$ contains an irrational point.

Comment: how do you know that each of the terms of $a_n$ are rational or 0 as you have said f(a_n)=0

Comment: There are uncountably infinitely many irrationals between two rationals. For $x\in\mathbb Q,x=0\;\&\;f(x)=0$ and $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q\;\&\;f(x)=0$ it is continuous.